# Django select option

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which has a select field (your color). In front of the select field, I have a button that produces a popup which allows users to create new color before they submit. I am submitting that color form via Ajax. After adding a new color to the database, the popup closes.
I want the newly added color to show in the select list without reloading the page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this by the same ajax where the `success` triggers. Code below may help a little :

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url where your view waits',
            data: {
                'post': "your data on post",
                },
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                  // here you can do DOM manipulation add new object to the list.
                  // You can also get data from backend in json format an then
                  // add it to your DOM.
                },
        });
    });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Will take a look at it and get back to you.